# 403 and 401 errors in ABP Framework not returning response body

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, abp

I'm working with ABP framework, I have an issue with abp version 5 and above. When I make a request to an endpoint and I'm not authorized, the response code is 401 which is what I expect, but the response body is empty. At first I suspected that this is the normal behavior and I need to handle the exception myself, but then I found in the app logs that the response I'm looking for is being logged but not returned.
[image]

The logs is showing:

```
 [01:18:04 WRN] ---------- RemoteServiceErrorInfo ----------
{
  "code": "Volo.Authorization:010001",
  "message": "Authorization failed! Given policy has not granted.",
  "details": null,
  "data": {},
  "validationErrors": null
}

[01:18:04 WRN] Exception of type 'Volo.Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException' was thrown.
Volo.Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException: Exception of type 'Volo.Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException' was thrown.
```

In the earlier versions of ABP (4.4.4 and before), this response was being returned normally.

I've tried handling the exception but I then saw that it is being catched somewhere in the framework. Not sure if this could be related to OpenIdDict, as in the earlier versions the abp was using IdentityServer.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `DefaultExceptionToErrorInfoConverter`.

You can find more info about it here:

https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/17949

I hope this answers your question as I have a similar requirement and found this solution, but never implemented it myself.